# for_each on a COM IEnumXxx interface?

Tags: c++, com, stl, enumerator

I've got a COM object that returns an IEnumUnknown. Is there anything out there that'll turn it into an STL-style iterator? So that I can do something like this:

```
IEnumUnkPtr pEnumUnk;
// ...something that fills in pEnumUnk...
MagicThing m(pEnumUnk);
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), DoSomethingWithUnk);
```

...or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the comstl project has what you need: http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classcomstl_1_1enumerator__sequence.html